# Get variable from url without going there:

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I am collecting an access_token for facebook web app

so, I have the following:

```
$fb_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent& .
client_id=132456789&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com . 
&scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence";
```

When I go to that URL it forwards me to:

```
mysite.com?access_token=5sdf5s5wrrg4e645e645
```

So how can I fire the URL and collect variable access_token without actually going there which obviously cannot happen... if that makes sense!

Comment: nope, I lost you near: `collect variable access_token`

Comment: @ChasingDeath don't even go there! ha ha

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you need to make a [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request programmatically and interpret the response. Practically it would be easier if you used a specialized "facebook connector" class. Did you check out [Facebook's developer docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to send a HTTP-Request manually and then work with the result

http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fire the URL and collect variable access_token without actually going there

You can't.

You can however actually go there *without sending the user's browser to that URL*, if that is what you mean. You can do that using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which makes that request serverside. You can then present the result to the user, or do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it - facebook sdk is daunting at times then all of a sudden it all makes stupid sense!

```
require '/home/***/public_html/pages/social_login/fb_lib/facebook.php';

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = '__APP_ID__';
$config[‘secret’] = '__SECRET__';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);


//TO GET ACCESS TOKEN
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```